# How do I add lines from a file to an array?

Tags: python, arrays

I am reading in specific lines from a file based on a timestamp using python. I want to then add these lines to an array. However, when I do this the array is empty. Here is my code:

```
def parse(self):
    with open(self.filename) as errorfile:
        data = []
        for line in errorfile:
            # Look in each line for Warning message
            if self.is_Warning(line):
                data.append(line)
            return data

def is_Warning(self,line):
    if line.find("Warning") >= 0:
        ts = time.strptime(line[:15].strip(), "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
        print "==================== %s" % ts
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your `is_Warning` function does not return `True` or `False` or anything else. Add `return True` in the `if` block.

You can also use the more pythonic and readable `"Warning" in line` instead of `line.find("Warning")>= 0`.

And also see [Chirila's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23309605/3456281).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this:

```
    for line in errorfile:
        # Look in each line for Warning message
        if self.is_Warning(line):
            data.append(line)
        return data
```

Should be:

```
    for line in errorfile:
        # Look in each line for Warning message
        if self.is_Warning(line):
            data.append(line)
    return data
```